# Gunzip a file on remote server without copying

Tags: shell

I have a file named `abc.tar.gz` on `server1` and wanted to extract it on `server2` using SSH and without copying it to the `server2`.

Tried like this, but doesn't work:

```
gunzip -c abc.tar.gz "ssh user@server2" | tar -xvf -
```

Comment: [‘*doesn't work*’, eh?](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)

Comment: 'it's not working.. any idea?'

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing stuffs. Try to understand what do you copy (and maybe also this answer).

Your program needs few steps:

1- read the file on remote server: `gunzip -c abc.tar.gz`

2- send the file to your machine: `| ssh user@server2`

3- and make ssh to execute a local program: (still on ssh) ` tar -xvf -

so `gunzip -c abc.tar.gz | ssh user@server2 tar -xvf -`

It server2 is a good machine (not a old embedded device), probably it is better to just use `cat` on server1 and do the `gunzip` on server2: less traffic to be sent, so probably also faster.

Please: try to understand it, before to copy and execute on your machine. There are man pages of all such commands.